# Get character offsets of beginning and end of selected text

Tags: javascript, angular

For a given string I am able to get the selected text with

```
var text = window.getSelection().toString();
```

and I am trying to get the character offset of the selected text.  I have tried

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset
```

for the character offset of the beginning of the selection and

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset
```

for the character offset of the end of the selection however this gives the incorrect result.

For example, for the example string

```
lskdjfldjf sdlkjfsdl jflsdk fjlksdjf lksdjfl sdjfl sdjflsdkjfskl
```

When I select the first word (i.e. everything up to the first space), the beginning offset is 41 and the end offset is 51 according to the above method.  The correct offsets should be 0 and 10.  I feel like I am somewhat on the right track since the difference between the offsets is correct but its just the values that are wrong.  Is there some way to programatically get the value that I should subtract from the offsets to get the correct offsets (41 in this case)?  Or is there a better method to get the offsets of the selected text?

UPDATE:

Here is the larger html block where this is happening

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Example {{i + 1}} of {{examples.length}}</strong></div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                            <div (mouseup)="showSelectedText(i)">
                                            {{example.labelled}}
                            </div>
                       </div>
    </div>
```

this is an angular2 app.  Where the function `showSelectedText()` contains the selection logic

Comment: if i select the first word in your string, i get the `baseOffset: 0` and `focusOffset: 10`. Not sure how you got 41 and 51

Comment: Can you reproduce this with JS fiddle?

Comment: @StrahinjaAjvaz I am using `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset` and `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset` please explain where `baseOffset` and `focusOffset` come from

Comment: Can you post the html you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of the HTML structure.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("text");

document.addEventListener("mouseup",function(){
    if(window.getSelection)
    {
        var text = window.getSelection().toString();
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        console.log(range.startContainer.textContent,
                    range.startOffset,
                    range.endOffset)
    }
},false);
```

```html
<div>
You made me a, you made me a Believer!
</div>
<div>You made me a, you made me a Believer!</div>
<div>You made me a, you made me a Believer!
</div>
```

Observe the HTML structure of the above snippet below,

[image: HTML structure of the example snippet]

Now select a line in the above output. On selecting,

1. **first line** - index starts with 5 - Text content with no tags are appended to the `body` tag with a `newline` character and a `tab` (4 spaces by default), which defaults the `startindex` to `5`.
2. **second line** - index starts with 1 - A new line character is added as per HTML snippet been written.
3. **third line** - Normal behaviour.
4. **fourth line** - index ends with a value 1 greater than the actual index - Appends a `newline` character at the end.

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseup",function(){
    if(window.getSelection)
    {
        var selectedtext = window.getSelection().toString();
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var content = range.startContainer.textContent;
        content = content.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');
        if(range.startContainer.parentElement.tagName=="BODY")
        {
            content = content.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/, '');
        }
        console.log(content, content.indexOf(selectedtext), content.indexOf(selectedtext)+selectedtext.length)
    }
},false);
```

```html
You made me a, you made me a Believer!

<div>
You made me a, you made me a Believer!
</div>
<div>You made me a, you made me a Believer!</div>
<div>You made me a, you made me a Believer!
</div>
```

The above snipper works perfectly, only on selecting the content in a single element. If selected in multiple elements, need to be modify the implementation.

Comment: I think this was the problem.  When I put the div tags on the same line as the text the offsets gave the correct results, thanks

Answer (score 0):

used below function that will return you the new range on the based on the document.

```js
restoreSelection = function(savedSel, doc) {
  var charIndex = 0;
  var range = doc.createRange();
  range.setStart(doc.body, 0);
  range.collapse(true);
  var nodeStack = [doc.body],
    node, foundStart = false,
    stop = false;
  savedSel.end = savedSel.end;
  while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
      var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
      if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
        range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
        foundStart = true;
      }
      if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) {
        range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
        stop = true;
      }
      charIndex = nextCharIndex;
    } else {
      var i = node.childNodes.length;
      while (i--) {
        nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return range;
}
```

savedSel : your range and doc will the document

this function will return you the new range with the offsets